# Thousand separator (.) and decimal place with , in SQL sybase

Tags: numbers, format, sybase

I am having the problem that I should format any number in the following style in SQL ( Sybase ).

5123456789,99 --> 5.123.456.789,99

The only way that I found was:

```
select convert(varchar, cast(5123456789.99 as money), 1) --> 5,123,456,789.99
```

but this is the other way around :(
Is it somehow possible to get the thousand operator with a dot instead of comma?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
           CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(money, 5123456789.99), 1), ',', ' '
       ), '.', ','
   ), ' ', '.'
);
```

It's not pretty though.

Comment: Thank you very much. That`s it! I thought there might be something better or something easier. I also thought about changing the language settings on Unix site but I have not found something there.